# How to iterate over a collection of objects already filtered by ng-repeat filters

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-directive, angularjs-ng-repeat

I have a collection of objects that AngularJS filters by a text search within a title property on each object.

After this filter has run, I am left with a set of items that matches this filter.

I would like to iterate over this subset of the list, after clicking a button, and change a property on the items that match this filter.

Is there an easy way to do this in AngularJS, or am I going to be doing this outside Angular and then updating the state manually in the controller?

Comment: Stack Overflow expects you to [try to solve your own problem first](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/261592/how-much-research-effort-is-expected-of-stack-overflow-users), as your attempts help us to better understand what you want. Please edit the question to show what you've tried, so as to illustrate a specific roadblock you're running into in a [minimal reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example). For more information, please see [How to Ask](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) and take the tour of the site.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It appears that within an ng-repeat you can do the following

> item in items | filter:x as results will store the fragment of the repeated items as results, but only after the items have been processed through the filter.

Answer (score 0):

When the user clicks the button you can get this values and make some change. But I think you need do it inside your controller.

Comment: So I need to perform this action after the user has filtered the set that I am repeating.

Comment: yes but you need a copy of the changed elements, and with filter you don't have any copy, it's only for present the data. you need do all your changes on controller. Because you need a copy of all changed elements.

Comment: After additional research it seems that I can pass the filtered items to a variable that is available to the controller.

Comment: Your filter can put any match on a temporary storage, and you get this elements on your controller.